# IndexError: string index out of range python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently making a cryptography file, it's supposed to take a user key and a user input, and work through it like a caesar cipher except it multiplies the key by 2 after each letter. After testing it, i ran into this error:

```
line 40, in <module>
encode("p", 16) line 15, in encode
if decoded_message[place_in_message] == letter:
IndexError: string index out of range`
```

here's the code that I was using:

```
import array as arr
alphabet = arr.array('u', ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]) 
decoded_message = input("What's your message? ")
amount_of_characters = (len(decoded_message))
key = int(input("What's your key? "))
place_in_message = 0
encoded_message = ""
_ = 0
def encode(letter, letterNum):
    global key
    global place_in_message
    global alphabet
    global decoded_message
    global encoded_message
    if decoded_message[place_in_message] == letter:
        if key + letterNum < 26:
            encoded_message = encoded_message + alphabet[letterNum + key]
            place_in_message = place_in_message + 1
            key = key * 2
        else:
            key = key - 26
            encoded_message = encoded_message + alphabet[letterNum + key]
            place_in_message = place_in_message + 1
for _ in range(amount_of_characters):
    encode("a", 1)
    encode("b", 2)
    encode("c", 3)
    encode("d", 4)
    encode("e", 5)
    encode("f", 6)
    encode("g", 7)
    encode("h", 8)
    encode("i", 9)
    encode("j", 10)
    encode("k", 11)
    encode("l", 12)
    encode("m", 13)
    encode("n", 14)
    encode("o", 15)
    encode("p", 16)
    encode("q", 17)
    encode("r", 18)
    encode("s", 19)
    encode("t", 20)
    encode("u", 21)
    encode("v", 22)
    encode("w", 23)
    encode("x", 24)
    encode("y", 25)
    encode("z", 26)
print(encrypted_message)
```

I'm not sure why this error is happening, I looked through my code and didn't see anything wrong.
Thanks for helping

Comment: Don't use _ as an actual variable = 0

Comment: [Variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python). You don't need to mark them as global in the function, you can still access them if you just remove those lines. You almost never need to use the `global` keyword in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to put a lot of effort into this answer because I'm bored, so first, let's clean up your code. (The code below works)

```
class MessageEncoder:
    def __init__(self, decoded_message, key):
        self.decoded_message, self.key = decoded_message, key

        self.alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s",
                         "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
        self.place_in_message = 0
        self.encoded_message = ""

        for c, char in enumerate(self.decoded_message):
            if char == " ":
                c -= 1
                continue
            self.encode(char, c)
        print(self.encoded_message)

    def encode(self, letter, letterNum):
        if self.decoded_message[self.place_in_message] == letter:
            if self.key + letterNum < 26:
                self.encoded_message += self.alphabet[letterNum + self.key]
                self.place_in_message += 1
                self.key *= 2
            else:
                self.key -= 26
                self.encoded_message += self.alphabet[letterNum + self.key]
                self.place_in_message += 1


MessageEncoder("Hello World", 1)
```

I'm not sure if I did what you were going for, if I made a mistake please let me know I will make it so that it does whatever.

Comment: There is no reason to make this a class instead of just a function. You should use `string.ascii_lowercase` instead of writing out the alphabet.

Comment: I made it a class to better organize it, also because there was a spam of globals which I just don't like.

Comment: And yes, I should have used string to get the alphabet, but he had already typed it out so I just didn't bother.